# perform a rotate transition on a scaled object CSS 3

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms, cakeyframeanimation

I have a series of objects all of which have different scaled value using the css 3 transform tag. My problem is that when I try to attach an animation on hover (in this case its a rotation) they return to their original/unscaled value i.e they all have the same size.

I am using a common keyframe animation for all the objects to save up on coding time and neatness.

Any hero has a solution?

Comment: Well It would help if you would show your css code. Only thing I could think of now is to scale the element in the hover part as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that :

1. the keyframe does not have the scale property that set the scale rate back to 0.
2. You didnt miss a `;` at the end of a line, and you didnt do any syntax mistake.

try to share your css code so we can find the problem.

Comment: Hey Guys I will post the code tonight as I am currently at work.